# Sentiment analysis of various lines of data

Tags: python, excel, text, analysis

I'm new to programming and do not have much experience yet. I understand some python codes, but not into detail.
I have an Excel file which contains log files of problems people encountered. The description of the problem is pasted as an email (so it's a bunch of text). I want to analyze all of these texts (almost 1.000 rows in Excel) at once, and I think Python can do this. 
The type of analysis I want to do is sentiment analysis (positive, neutral, negative) or I want to see the main problem out of the text. I don't know if the second one is possible.

I copied the emails that are listed in the Excel file, to a .txt file, so now every rule is one message. How can I use Python to analyze every single rule as one message and let it show me the sentiment or the main problem?

I'd appreciate the help

Comment: Read the [NLTK book!](http://www.nltk.org/book/)

Answer (score 0):

Sentiment analysis is a fairly large problem in computer science/language. How specific did you want to get?

I'd recommend looking into Text-Processing for simple SA.

Their API docs are here, http://text-processing.com/docs/sentiment.html, which will return a simple pos and neg score for your text.

If you want anything more specific, I'd recommend looking into the IBM Watson, specifically Natural Language Understanding https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding.html